# How to check NSDictionary for Key Value pairs without making it crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently doing something  like this

```
NSDictionary *imageDataDictionary = nil;
imageDataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)metadataItem.value;
if(imageDataDictionary != nil)
{
    if ([imageDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] != nil) <---Crashes
    {
    }
}
```

The app crashes on

```
if ([imageDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] != nil)
```

because it has 0 key value pairs.
I wanted to know what would the right way be to check if a NSDictionary is valid and if it has any key value pairs

This is the messages

```
2015-04-19 15:56:37.255 MBlast[61278:2115186] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c16a7e0'
```

Comment: It doesn't crash in that case https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey: Also, you don't need to check imageDataDictionary for nil, it will work without it

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: My bet is that `metadataItem.value` is not a dictionary.

Comment: Don't attempt to do `objectForKey` on an NSData object.  It's never going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting an object of unspecified type to an NSDictionary. That tell the compiler "trust me, this is a dictionary."

If the object is NOT a dictionary, you'll crash. That is almost certainly what's going on here. Add some error checking:

```
if (![mediadataItem.value isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
  return; //The object isn't a dictionary. Bail.
NSDictionary *imageDataDictionary;
imageDataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)metadataItem.value;
if(imageDataDictionary != nil)
{
    if ([imageDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] != nil) <---Crashes
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it wasnt a dictionary. Thanks

Comment: @Rajeshwar - The exception message told you it wasn't a dictionary, if you'd bothered to look at it.  `[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector`